# Php find specific days per week

Tags: php

How can I query with datetime.

My code result:

```
08-06-2019, Saturday
15-06-2019, Saturday
22-06-2019, Saturday
09-06-2019, Sunday
16-06-2019, Sunday
23-06-2019, Sunday
```

I want to:

```
08-06-2019, Saturday
09-06-2019, Sunday
15-06-2019, Saturday
16-06-2019, Sunday
22-06-2019, Saturday
23-06-2019, Sunday
```

My code:

```
<?php
$week       = 1;
$days       = array(7, 8);
$start_date = new DateTime('2019-06-01');
$end_date   = new DateTime('2019-06-16');

$interval   = new DateInterval("P{$week}W");
$period     = new DatePeriod($start_date, $interval, $end_date);

foreach($days as $day){
    foreach($period as $date){
        $date->modify("+{$day} day");
        echo $date->format('d-m-Y') . ', ' . $date->format('l') . '<br />';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you're trying to achieve, but this code seems to be working:

```
$week       = 1;
$days       = array(7, 8);
$start_date = new DateTime('2019-06-01');
$end_date   = new DateTime('2019-06-16');

$interval   = new DateInterval("P{$week}W");
$period     = new DatePeriod($start_date, $interval, $end_date);

foreach($period as $date) {
    $date->modify("+7 days");
    echo $date->format('d-m-Y, l') . '<br />';

    $sunday = clone $date;
    $sunday->modify("+1 day");
    echo $sunday->format('d-m-Y, l') . '<br />';
}
```

Result:

```
08-06-2019, Saturday
09-06-2019, Sunday
15-06-2019, Saturday
16-06-2019, Sunday
22-06-2019, Saturday
23-06-2019, Sunday
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I add other days?

Comment: I am listing with post box with select box.

Comment: What other days? You're asking me questions like you have no idea what you're doing...

Comment: I have 3 fields
1- Startdate
2- End Date
3- Days (Select menu)
Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday

I want to list specific days by date range.

For example;
Start date: 2019-06-01
End date: 2019-06-09
Days: Sunday, Monday (Single or multi select)

Result:
2019-06-02 - Sunday
2019-06-03 - Monday
2019-06-09 - Sunday

Was it descriptive?